# CocoaPod and Unit Tests for Swift Framework

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, cocoapods

So I'm having trouble locating the definitive answer after trawling Cocoapods.org

I know Quick and Nimble are used for Unit Tests, at least for objective-C, however when creating a CocoaPod in Swift as a framework, I read somewhere there is only one choice, but what is that choice?

What is THE framework I have to use for my swift,framework cocoa pod to have it count as tested, as it's not XCTest obviously.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure Swift CocoaPod you can use Quick/Nimble or XCTest.  I recommend reading the excerpt here from CocoaPods.org in regards to creating a new Swift framework (including unit tests).

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html

I recently created a Swift CocoaPod using the "pod lib create" command and using only XCTest.  Using the provided command line approach you can start a new project to include unit tests and a demo app, if desired and all the setup is handled for you.  The only configuration I needed was to ensure the pod target had enable_testability = YES so that your unit tests can read your pod classes.